# Microphone not accessible in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, microphone

My daughter needs to use a music practice site that only runs in Chrome (required for a class). I have set the microphone to "Allowed" when the pop-up asked. Chrome shows the camera icon in the right side of the address bar with the message "This page is accessing your microphone", but the website still shows an error message that the microphone is unavailable.

I have tried several websites with no luck. I can use the microphone normally in Firefox.

I did some searching, but most of the results I've found are the same generic steps for setting the "Allow Microphone" permission.

Details:

- tried several different websites using Chrome, all with the same issue
- the sites I was able to try in Firefox worked fine
- two separate PCs have this problem (Windows 10 Home)
- both of those machines have clean installs of Chrome, downloaded today. No plugins or extensions are running.
- I have tried disabling hardware acceleration in the Chrome settings
- tried running in incognito mode
- checked microphone properties to make sure "allow exclusive control" was disabled
- removed and re-added site to the "allowed" list in Settings > Privacy > Content > Microphone
- verified that the site is not in the "blocked" list in Settings > Privacy > Content > Microphone
- Using Win7 on an old laptop, the site works properly with the microphone(it's a very old backup system, though, and doesn't operate very well)
- the laptop is running the same version of Chrome (auto updated today while I was trying to solve this)

Anything additional that I can try would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer.

I had to go to Microphone Privacy Settings, and turn "Allow apps to access your microphone" to "On". Changing this setting made both my desktop and laptop completely unresponsive. After a reboot, I was able to use my microphone in Chrome.

I had assumed that this setting only affected Modern UI apps, since Firefox was still able to function, and Chrome does not appear in the list of apps to give individual permission to. Firefox will still work, even if I turn off the setting again.

I know this sounds like a pretty simple thing to overlook, but while I was searching for my solution I have seen this issue covered at around a dozen sites, both as troubleshooting tips from websites that need microphone access, and as unsolved questions on forums, and none that I saw offered this suggestion. Hopefully this will help out a few other people.

This also affects Opera, which had the same behavior as Chrome.