# Microphone doesn't work using Meet only in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio, microphone

I am facing an issue with the microphone using Meet in Google Chrome, Windows 10.
I can have normal meeting using Meet in Edge or Firefox, but I can't using Chrome because the microphone doesn't work.

I am using the latest Chrome version.
In Chrome settings, Meet (
`https://meet.google.com:443)` has access to microphone. Meet's (Chrome) settings are set in the same way they are set in Meet (Firefox, Edge).
In Windows settings, Chrome has access granted to microphone.
I already tried to remove and install Chrome, but it didn't work.

What can I do in order to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1414152/microphone-not-accessible-in-chrome?rq=1)

Comment: @Ramhound yes, this is what I meant here (In Windows settings, Chrome has access granted to microphone)